# ExtJS Store dynamically filter on already filtered store

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, store

I am creating a SearchAsYouType Combobox tied to a Store.
It features tokenizing the input into words and match it (for now) against all properties of an Object:

```
{"id": "id_someid",
 "lastName": "Porker",
 "firstName": "Peter"}
```

I decided to create the Filters on the fly when the input of the combobox changes:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SearchFilterController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

   views: [
    'SearchAsYouTypeCombo'
   ],

   configureFiltersBeforeQuery: function(queryPlan) {
    //add filter per word token

    comboBox = queryPlan.combo;
    queryString = queryPlan.query;
    words = queryString.split(/[,\s]+/);
    myStore = comboBox.getStore(); 

    myStore.clearFilter(false); //I also tried without this line, did not help

    if(!Ext.isEmpty(queryString))
    {
        //create a filter per word
        filters = [];
        Ext.Array.each(words,
           function(word, index, wordsArray){ 
             console.log('NEW FILTER: word: ' + word);
             filterAllPropertiesFilter = 
                Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                   { filterFn: function(item){
                        match = false;
                        Ext.Object.each(item.data,
                        function (property, value){
                        //match beginning of word
                        match = match || (String(value).toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(word.toLowerCase(), 0) === 0);
                    return !match; //do not check other properties when match is found
                });
                return match;
            }});
            filters.push(filterAllPropertiesFilter);
            return true;
        },
        this,
        false);
        myStore.addFilter(filters);
    }
    return true;
},

init: function(application) {
    this.control({
        'SearchAsYouTypeCombo': {
            beforequery: this.configureFiltersBeforeQuery
        }
    });
}
```

});

EDIT: There is a "Kevin Bacon" in my Store.
Let's say that none of the LastNames of the other Persons in the local Store starts with "Ba", but there is someone else whose firstName is "Barry". So when I type in the search query "Ba" I want to see "Kevin Bacon" and "Barry White" as results. This works.

**But here is what I cannot accomplish:**
 When I now go on extending the searchString to "Ba, Ke" I don't want the code to interate over all Persons in my Store again when applying the filter. I want the upcoming filter to only check against the left two results from the previous filter.
I kinda want to apply a filter upon another filter.

Comment: To be a little bit clearer. The filters per word do apply on each other, but on every keystroke the first word is filtered against all records from the store again.

Comment: And what if I change my input from "Ba, Ke" to "Be, Ke"?

Comment: As in my current solution I build Filters on basis of words changing a word might result in losing a filter and creating a new one. And as long as it was not the last word, then I would need to re-apply all the filters.
EDIT: But this brings up the idea to somehow manage the filters on controller level and keep track of the words. And maybe even about if a word is changed or just extended. But still I am missing the link on how to apply a filter to a store only on the set of records already resulting from an earlier filter.

Comment: I've posted a solution to achieve what you want. Good luck finishing your component. But also, you should really take care of not polluting the global scope, that's a very bad "code smell". One should always use `var` when declaring local variables.

Comment: store.setFilters(queryString.split(',').makeFilters()); store.filter();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to accomplish what you want using the store's filters because these methods all end up filtering on the whole dataset. So you'll need to apply your filter yourself!

In order to do that, we need to replicate the code from [`Ext.data.Store#filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-filter), except for the part that restores the whole dataset before filtering.

That gives us:

```
// -- Ensure that our current filter is not stalled ----------------

// Clear our filtering if the query string has changed in a way
// that invalidate the current filtering
if (
    // previous filter is stalled
) {
    myStore.data = myStore.snapshot;
    delete myStore.snapshot;
}

// -- Create your new or updated filter ----------------------------

var filter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(record) {
        // your filtering logic
    }
});

// -- Apply the filter to the currently filtered data --------------

myStore.snapshot = myStore.snapshot || myStore.data.clone();

// !!!
// Here's the essential difference. We filter from the filtered dataset:
myStore.data = myStore.data.filter(myFilter);

// Instead of starting again from the unfiltered snapshot like in the original code:
//me.data = me.snapshot.filter(filters);

myStore.constructGroups();

if (myStore.sorters.length && myStore.sortOnFilter && !myStore.remoteSort) {
    myStore.sort();
} else {
    // fire datachanged event if it hasn't already been fired by doSort
    myStore.fireEvent('datachanged', myStore);
    myStore.fireEvent('refresh', myStore);
}

// This line's probably useless since filters haven't actually changed...
//myStore.fireEvent('filterchange', myStore, myStore.filters.items);
```

As I've hinted in my previous comment, you'll obviously need a way to detect when the query string has changed in a way that render the current filtering outdated. I've added a mock condition at the beginning of the code to show you how to clear this hacky filtering when that happens.

Comment: For clarity's sake, you should probably override or extend `Ext.data.store` and put this code in two methods like `quickFilter` and `cleanQuickFilter`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just wanted to ask if what you suggested in your comment makes more sense. I will test this.

Comment: You may want to take some time to find really good names for the methods, since that will create some new API, but that's definitely some logic that belongs in the store... I haven't tested the code, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually your solution works, although all the filters are still present and get applied again on the data (which is now a subset).
To avoid this I tried a new approach:  
Just take the last word, remove all previous filters without throwing an event or applying the filter change, then only apply the new filter. This does exactly what I specified. Specification was poor.
Conceptual issue: Query "Ba, Ke", then backspace to "Ba". For X words on the query this would need applying all word filters to the original data set again. Cannot keep track on all filtered data states of the last x words.